# SQL Help - Counting Records Once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to get a count of the total number of borrowers (cnsmr_accnt.cnsmr_id) and the sum total principal and interest balance for those borrowers for each year.  My code below accomplishes this but I need to count each borrower only once (the first year) across all years.

```
SELECT DISTINCT      
MIN(DATEPART(YEAR, UDEFDebtInfo.UDEFDebtPlacementDt)) AS [First Placement Year],
COUNT(cnsmr_accnt.cnsmr_id) AS [Borrower Count],
SUM(UDEFDebtInfo.UDEFDebtOrigPrincBal) AS [Principal Balance], 
SUM(UDEFDebtInfo.UDEFDebtOrigIntBal) AS [Int Balance]
FROM UDEFDebtInfo 
INNER JOIN cnsmr_accnt ON UDEFDebtInfo.cnsmr_accnt_id = cnsmr_accnt.cnsmr_accnt_id 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, UDEFDebtInfo.UDEFDebtPlacementDt)
```

For example, if a borrower had a UDEFDebtPlacementDt in 2008 with a principal balance of $500 and a interest balance of $100 and UDEFDebtPlacementDt in 2009 with a principal balance of $1,000 and a interest balance of $200 then the borrower should only be counted in year 2008 with a principal balance of $1,500 and a interest balance of $300.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation on the OVER clause.  I think this could be your answer.  You will need the PARTITION part as well.

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT cnsmr_accnt.cnsmr_id) maybe?

Comment: If you added scripts to create the data you want, it would be easier for someone to help.  As well as expected output.  Dean may be right that all you need is the Distinct in the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the borrower is `cnsmr_id` who has several accounts in `cnsmr_accnt`. You want the sums and the first year *per* borrower. So you must *group by* `cnsmr_id`.

Once you have this data, you want aggregations *per* year, so you'd *group by* year then.

```
SELECT
  first_placemant_year AS [First Placement Year],
  COUNT(*) AS [Borrower Count],
  SUM(principal_balance) AS [Principal Balance],
  SUM(int_balance) AS [Int Balance]
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    ca.cnsmr_id,
    MIN(DATEPART(YEAR, di.UDEFDebtPlacementDt)) AS first_placemant_year,
    SUM(di.UDEFDebtOrigPrincBal) AS principal_balance, 
    SUM(di.UDEFDebtOrigIntBal) AS int_balance
  FROM UDEFDebtInfo di
  INNER JOIN cnsmr_accnt ca ON di.cnsmr_accnt_id = ca.cnsmr_accnt_id 
  GROUP BY ca.cnsmr_id
) borrowers
GROUP BY first_placemant_year
ORDER BY first_placemant_year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nested query in select should work. For principal, try something like below query, and add the interest the same way

```
SELECT DISTINCT      
MIN(DATEPART(YEAR, UDEFDebtInfo.UDEFDebtPlacementDt)) AS [First Placement Year]
, COUNT(cnsmr_accnt.cnsmr_id) AS [Borrower Count]
, ( SELECT SUM(UDEFDebtInfo.UDEFDebtOrigPrincBal) FROM UDEFDebtInfo u WHERE u.cnsmr_accnt_id=UDEFDebtInfo.cnsmr_accnt_id) AS [Principal Balance]
FROM UDEFDebtInfo 
INNER JOIN cnsmr_accnt ON UDEFDebtInfo.cnsmr_accnt_id = cnsmr_accnt.cnsmr_accnt_id 
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, UDEFDebtInfo.UDEFDebtPlacementDt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use DISTINCT with your COUNT:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT cnsmr_accnt.cnsmr_id) AS [Borrower Count],
```

Answer (score -1):

Do not use nested queries. As User 3083310 suggested use a count(*) over (Partition by. Your performance will be over 80% better then a nested query.